# performance issue with app service in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have just started to work on azure portal. I need to deploy 8 applications on azure portal for this I am using app service, I am using P2v2 service plan and into this plan i am creating 8 app services and deployed the code, but when users browsing the sites, performance of sites are too slow I tried to stop all app services except 2 app services which i need but still performance slow. Even I change plan from P2v2 to S2 now but still performance is not well. Can anyone suggest how can I improve my app service performace.

Thanks 
Sandy

Comment: You need to check if the performance issues are from the host because the P2V2 is good plan. Maybe you can tey to increase your instances.

Comment: As is, it's impossible to help you.  Start by defining "slow performance" with some metrics, describe your app (language, database, etc) and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask